# Accessing hash reference in perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am wondering if the following is possible to do in perl. It will save 40-50 lines of code.

I have a hash data structure like following:

```
hash_Ref->{a}->{b}->{c}->{d}->{e}->{'count'}=30
```

I am wondering is there a way I can do the following:

```
my $hash_ref_1 = ash_Ref->{a}->{b}->{c}->{d};
```

and then use:

```
$hash_ref_2->{e}.
```

So in summary I want to store hash reference till a point "x" in the hierarchy  in a variable and then access the reference which the point "x" points to. I think this is more clear in the example above.

More details

I tried couple of things but doesnt seem to work for me. I am copying the code but not all the things I tried to copy hash. Also the output I am getting is something like this

```
 $VAR1 = {
          'e' => {
                   'count' => 2
                 },
          'c' => {
                   'count' => 2
                 },
          'a' => {
                   'count' => 2
                 },
          'b' => {
                   'count' => 2
                 },
          'd' => {
                   'count' => 2
                 }
        };
```

where I would expect something like this:

```
'a' => { 'count' => 2, 'b' => { 'count' => 2, 'c' => ......} }
```

Here's some code I used:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array1 = ('a','b','c','d','e');
my @array2 = ('a','b','c','d','e');
my $hash;

 build_hash(\@array1);
 build_hash(\@array2);


sub build_hash {

    my @array = @{shift @_};

    my $hash_ref;

    for ( my $i =0 ;  $i < scalar @array ; $i++ ){

        print "$i \t $array[$i] \n";
         if ( exists $hash->{$array[$i]} ){

            $hash->{$array[$i]}->{'count'}++;
        }

        else{

            $hash->{$array[$i]}->{'count'}=1;
        }
    }
    print Dumper($hash);

}
```

I want to build a hierarchy of hash references based on the elements in the perl in the sequential order and possibly using one loop like I have tried to do in the sample code.

Thanks!
-Abhi

Comment: What have you tried? Does it work? If not, why not? [perllol and perldsc are must-reads](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html)

Comment: Just a comment on style: from `perldoc perlreftut` (http://p3rl.org/reftut) the "arrow rule" `hash_Ref->{a}->{b}->{c}->{d}->{e}->{'count'}` can be written as `hash_Ref->{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{'count'}`

Comment: why should `$hash_ref_2` contain anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# 'a' => { 'count' => 2, 'b' => { 'count' => 2, 'c' => ......} }

sub build_hash {
    $_[0] ||= {};
    my $hash = shift;
    for (@_) {
        $hash = $hash->{$_} ||= {};
        ++$hash->{count};
    }
}

build_hash($hash, @array1);
build_hash($hash, @array2);
```

If you wanted to use autovivification, you could write it as follows:

```
sub build_hash {
    my $p = \shift;
    for (@_) {
        $p = \( $$p->{$_} );
        ++$$p->{count};
    }
}

build_hash($hash, @array1);
build_hash($hash, @array2);
```

See also: [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDiver)

Comment: @ikegami : Thanks a lot. Just wondering if you would recommend any good resource/s to get a good grip on these techniques in perl.

Comment: @Ahbi, You were always modifying the same hash. You wanted to modify other hashes. Those hashes didn't exist. Therefore, you needed to create them. Your problem had nothing to do with Perl, so no book of Perl techniques would help.

Comment: @ikegami : I should have been more explicit. I wanted to ask about a good resource on complex data structures in perl.                      Also could you tell me the rationale behind   $_[0] ||= {}; in the first program. I am surely missing something.

Comment: @Abhi, In my version, `$hash` is not a global. If you create a hash reference in local var `$hash` (say through autovivification), it won't affect the variable in the caller. On the other hand, modifying `$_[0]` will change the variable in the caller.

Comment: @ikegami : thanks a lot for your help so far. you are definitely helping me learn new things that I dint know about perl. I have another follow up question about program. Could you please explain how the line  $hash = $hash->{$_} ||= {} will work. So each time there is a new entry an annonymous hash is created but how does it get mereged into the main big hash with the hierarchy. I am still confused on this part.

Comment: @Abhi, `$hash = $hash->{$_} ||= {};` is the same as `$hash->{$_} ||= {}; $hash = $hash->{$_};`. There's never any merging since we build from the root to the leaf, not from the leaf to the root.

Answer (score 0):

This should work pretty much like you think it should work.  As a side note, sometimes when you have hash of hash of hash of...what you really wanted in the first place was one hash with a compund key, like $h{"$a,$b,$c"} instead of $h{$a}{$b}{$c}.  Just something to keep in mind. I don't know if it is applicable here.

Comment: @frankc : I have put some more details + full code in my original question.

Comment: @frankc: I don't have the details to prove it, but that sounds like a scary and unnecessary wrench to though into the mix. No downvote, but I wouldn't use that!

Comment: You think a compound key is harder to understand than a 6 layer deep data structure? I have never measured it, but i bet the compound key is more efficient as well.

Comment: In fact I think that the compound is harder to read than the nested personally, but lets accept your premise. Are you going to promise me that you are never going to use a "," in your hash keys. I know its not common, but what if you make a large system based on it and someone breaks that commitment, your whole data structure breaks. Further to use it, you need to split keys on commas: extra unnecessary work. What if you wanted to add some data to one of the keys; that used to be a hash, easy to tuck more info into it, now its part of a comma separated list, not an individual unit!

Comment: In the end, its not necessary and does not help here anyway. Since he is new, lets not confuse him with ill advised tricks and teach him to use proper Perl. He can screw it up later if he wants, when he knows what hes doing.

Comment: One more thing: Hash lookup must be far faster than the hand rolled extraction algorithm that you would have to write to find certain elements, which would be prone to bugs for unusual keys or patterns.

Comment: -1: Since one cannot represent `'a' => { 'count' => 2, 'b' => { 'count' => 2, 'c' => ......} }` in your "notation" this answer doesn't even help the OP.

Comment: The op did not clarify his question until after I posted my answer, as noted by the op in the above comment. There is no need to "promise not to use a comma" as a comma is an example of a delimiter, not a rule. It is up to the programmer to pick carefully. If you often need access to the independent parts of the key and must split often, then this is not the right approach. I did not say it is always the right approach. I believe programmers can be trusted to use their brain to find the a good solution rather than use overengineered solutions that whose cost outweight its benefits